# How can I generate nested json output using FOR JSON PATH from table with key-value in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json, nested-json

The table containing the key-value also has a `ParentID` column. This column contains the id of its parent. I want to get a nested json using these.

Key-value table:

```
create table #temp
(
    [Id] int, 
    [Key] nvarchar(100),
    [Value] nvarchar(max),
    [ParentId] int
)


insert into #temp select 1,'help','',null
insert into #temp select 2,'info','',1
insert into #temp select 3,'contact','example',1
insert into #temp select 4,'SSS','',1
insert into #temp select 5,'title','example',2
insert into #temp select 6,'text','example',2
insert into #temp select 7,'title','example',4
insert into #temp select 8,'text','',4
insert into #temp select 9,'0','',8
insert into #temp select 10,'1','',8
insert into #temp select 11,'title','example',9
insert into #temp select 12,'text','example',9
insert into #temp select 13,'title','example',10
insert into #temp select 14,'text','example',10
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "help": {
    "info": {
      "title": "example",
      "text": "example"
    },
    "contact": "example",
    "SSS": {
      "title": "example",
      "text": [
        {
          "title": "example",
          "text": "example"
        },
        {
          "title": "example",
          "text": "example"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't with `FOR JSON`, as SQL Server does not support dynamic keys. You could use `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`, which version of SQL Server do you have? Or you could do a recursive `JSON_MODIFY`

Comment: @Charlieface I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315577/nested-json-with-dynamic-query